# How can I restore the menu item for openinga project in IntelliJ from Window File Explorer?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have 2023.3.3 IntelliJ IDEA installed. I used to have a context menu on folders in File Explorer that was something like "Open folder as project". This is very handy (and serves as a workaround for the File/Folder tree in load projects window in IntelliJ being extremely slow).

Well, I installed an older version of IDEA temporarily. During install, I selected the option that results in this context menu item being present. Then I uninstalled the older version and now the menu item does not appear.

I am guessing there must be some way within IDEA to enable this again, but I didn't find it. I tried to reinstall 2023.3.3, but it says the install folder must be empty. I don't want to uninstall and reinstall because it would be a pain to have to set everything back up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005182840-How-to-add-Open-this-folder-with-IDEA-in-windows-right-click-menu- .

The easiest solution is to uninstall the current version but keep the settings and then reinstall it again, see the uninstall dialog but not check any options to keep all settings.
[image]